# Mass Mailing Tool Template using Google AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating a Mass Mailing Template for me to modify and use when I need to send similar emails to many people. The information required are in the spreadsheet, however I have missing parts in the code.

[This is the MMT Template](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jFCpx-CGJMS-46d5ZASFJU0E1XOQ6LZnAUie1yNP83w/edit?usp=sharing)

Missing parts I need help with:

1. Add codes for Name of the Sender, Reply-To & BCC To
2. I also want to track when an email was sent (date & time) & to whom (Recipient email) & what email was sent (Subject) in another tab in the same spreadsheet (Sent Email Log).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SUGGESTION

Using the [Advanced parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#advanced-parameters) for the **sendEmail** method & [appendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents), you can achieve your goal.

**The edited script below will do the following:**

1. Get data from your **MMT Template**
2. Identify the sender information *(Name of the Sender, Reply To, BCC To)*
3. Read email data to be processed from row `12` onward on the **MMT Template** sheet
4. Iterate on each row and send email based on the email recipient information
5. On every email sent, an audit log gets appended on the **Sent Email Log** sheet.

### Tweaked Script

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Mass Email')
    .addItem('Send Email', 'processTemplateData')
    .addToUi();
}

function processTemplateData() { // Get the sheet data from the MMT Template
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MMT Template");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //get all data from the sheet 
  var senderName = data[5][2];
  var replyTo = data[6][2];
  var bccTo = data[7][2];

  data.forEach((getEmailData, index) => { //Get every email data from row 12 onward
    index < 11 ? null : sendEmail(getEmailData, senderName, replyTo, bccTo) //Only process data from row 12 or index #11 from the array variable "data"
  });
}

function sendEmail(emailData, senderName, replyTo, bccTo) { //Send email
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    name: senderName,
    to: emailData[1],
    subject: emailData[2],
    htmlBody: emailData[3],
    bcc: bccTo,
    replyTo: replyTo
  });
  trackSentEmail(emailData[1],emailData[2]); //Track email that was send  Sent Email Log
}

function trackSentEmail(email,subject) { //Save send email info into the 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sent Email Log");
  sheet.appendRow([new Date,email,subject]); //Append the sent email on the Sent Email Log sheet
}
```

### Demonstration

- *Sample Sender Data* from the **MMT Template** sheet.

> [image]

- *After pressing the **Send Email** custom menu on the spreadsheet, here is the email message received by the sample **recipient***

> [image]

- *The **Sent Email Log** sheet.*

> [image]

### References

- [sendEmail() Advanced Parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#advanced-parameters)
- [appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)

Comment: Thank you Irvin, this works perfectly. Appreciate you assistance!